# Install specific version of tailwind-rn

Tags: react-native, version, tailwind-css

I just got into mobile development.
I am in the process of following this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJaFIGjyRms&t=1384s" to create my first app.
But I have a problem when installing tailwind-rn (at the 23rd minute), I followed everything as in the tutorial but my app tells me that "tw is not a function", after several research I understood that my installation of tailwind was perhaps not the good one and that it is necessary to use tailwind 3.0.1 because it is a stable version and is fonctionnal for this.

My first question is: do you think this is the solution?

My second question: What is the command line to install a specific version of tailwind-rn?

Answer (score 0):

In order to install any package with specific version you can do it in this way:

`npm i 'package_name'@'package_version'`

In your situation:

`npm i tailwind-rn@3.0.1`